# 18.04 Nvidia drivers installed but not used

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg

BIG EDIT :

As suggested by @marmayogi, because I did a fresh install of 18.04, here are the new outputs of some commands :

```
$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
```

```
$ ls /sys/firmware/efi/
config_table  esrt              fw_vendor  runtime-map  vars
efivars       fw_platform_size  runtime    systab
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       produit: GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile]
       fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       ressources: irq:154 mémoire:ec000000-ecffffff mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff mémoire:d0000000-d1ffffff portE/S:3000(taille=128) mémoire:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Intel Corporation
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:153 mémoire:eb000000-ebffffff mémoire:80000000-8fffffff portE/S:4000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

```
$ dkms status
nvidia, 390.116, 4.18.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm            757760  0
nvidia_drm             40960  0
nvidia_modeset       1048576  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              14376960  14 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        172032  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   458752  25 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
```

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
    Subsystem: Dell Device 087d
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 087d
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

```
$ sudo prime-select query
nvidia
```

Also, after some more investigation, I realized that (for some reason) wayland was used, that is probably the reason why it's not working. I saw somewhere on the internet that the nvidia drivers where not yet supported under wayland.

As I use gnome, I noticed that I could choose to run the session with "gnome with Xorg" when logging in. But If I choose this option, the session can't be opened, and I go back to the logging screen.

output of :

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001CBAsv00001028sd0000087Dbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` 3. `sudo lshw -c video` and 4. `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`

Comment: @Marmayogi I edited my post ! Thanks for helping

Comment: Please edit your question and post output of the following command: `dkms status`

Comment: An update : I did a fresh install of 18.04 and I still have exactly the same issue ...

Comment: As you made a **fresh install of 18.04**, please edit your question and **update the output** of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` 3. `sudo lshw -c video`  4. `dkms status` 5. `lsmod | grep nvidia` 6. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and 7. `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"`. Please avoid appending, just overwrite on already existng output, so that post will not be longer. @Antoine Pirrone, we will solve this problem, however! Please report to `@marmayogi`

Comment: What is the output of the command `sudo prime-select query`? Does it show `nvidia`?

Comment: Edit file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and remove comment `#` from the line **#WaylandEnable=false**. By uncommenting the above line, your system will use the Xorg display manager instead of `Wayland`. **Reboot your system**. When you make a GUI login, you will see a `cog` icon. If you click the icon, there will be options popped out: `Ubuntu` and `Ubuntu on Wayland`. You select `Ubuntu` and try to login. If you have problems then reconfigure the Xorg display server with command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` and **reboot**. This time you will succeed with GUI login  `Ubuntu` display Manager.

Comment: @Marmayogi I already tried setting WaylandEnable to false, when rebooting I could not event use a tty terminal, I had to boot on a live session to edit back the file ...

Comment: There is a way to get a `tty` and you need not use any USB bootable stick. Reboot your system and press `shift` key to enter into GRUB menu. Use Up/Dn arrows to select `Ubuntu` and then press `e`. A screen will appear, and look for the line `linux`. Use up/Dn arrows and reach that line. Press `end` key to reach end of line containing `linux`. Enter `3`. Press `F10` or `Ctrl+X` to boot. You will be taken to terminal `tty` and there you enter your login `username` and `password`. Now you may revert your settings. After your work is over, type `reboot`.

Comment: Now make a GUI login with display manager `Ubuntu on Wayland`, no problem!  And Open up a terminal with `"Ctrl+Alt+T"`. You reconfigure the Xorg display server with command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` followed by a `reboot`. After reboot, you attempt a GUI login  (use `cog` icon to switch to `Ubuntu`) on `'Ubuntu'` display manager. Now check your Nivida graphics is working?

Comment: doing sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg did not change anything ... I can't boot on GUI login screen with WaykandEnable=false uncommented, logging with the 'Ubuntu' profile behaves the same as before : I instantly get back to the login screen

Comment: You let  `#WaylandEnable=false` to continue. Don't disturb.  If `gdm3` has problems, then choose `lightdm` as a workaround. Open up a terminal and issue command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. There will be a window popped up. Use `Up/Dn` arrows and place cursor on `lightdm`. Hit `spacebar` to select it. Then hit `tab` to move to `OK` and finally type `return`. Now issue one more command: `sudo service lightdm restart` and you will find that X restarts to work. Issue command echo `$XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and check the output is  `x11`. If it is so, please check Nvidia after a **reboot**.

Comment: After restarting lightdm, I get a blank black screen with a blinking cursor, same after rebooting

Comment: Is it a laptop? Is it dual booted? If it is so, does Nvidia work in Windows 10 without any trouble?

Comment: It is a laptop with only Ubuntu. But when I was on 16.04 with the same laptop, nvidia drivers were working fine

Comment: Please upgrade your [Nvidia driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) to the [latest version 418](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145182/en-us) for ubuntu. Instead of manullay installing latest Nvidia driver, it is prefered to install through repository. Issue this command `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` which should produce a list of Nvidia drivers, highlighting and recommending the latest Nvidia-driver (displaying version number such as 418) to install. Please post the output (don't try to install immediately).

Comment: I updated the post with the output of sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

Comment: Please issue the following commands: 1. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` 2. `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and 3. `sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda*`. Then issue the following two commands `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` and `dpkg -l | grep -i cuda`. Please observe that both the commands should return an empty result. Please report your observation and after which let us continue with Nvidia installation instructions.

Comment: Let us enter into a chat session @Antoine Pirrone

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93462/discussion-on-question-by-antoine-pirrone-18-04-nvidia-drivers-installed-but-not).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing indcates that nvidia driver is not used, since lspci says:

```
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

But maybe your PC uses integrated GPU instead. Have you tried to change your default GPU in BIOS? Or disable integrated graphics completly?